# Calculate sub total emberjs

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-controllers

I create a shop cart. I using fixture adapter.
My models

```
App.Clothing = DS.Model.extend({
      name:     DS.attr('string')
    , category: DS.attr('string')
    , img:      DS.attr('string')
    , price:    DS.attr('number')
    , num:      DS.attr('number')
    , fullPrice: function(){
        return this.get('price') + " $";
    }.property('price')
})

App.CartRecord = App.Clothing.extend({
    numInCart:DS.attr('number',{defaultValue:1})
    , fullPrice: function(){
        return this.get('price')*this.get('numInCart');
    }.property('numInCart','price')
})
App.CartRecord.FIXTURES = [];
```

Route

```
App.CartRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.find('cartRecord');
    }
})
```

And my controller

```
App.CartController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
    totalPrice: 0
});
```

How i can calculate a total price?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put together a reduceComputed property for `sum`. Here are a few links for inspiration: [one](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/3327), [two](https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-cpm/pull/10/files), and [three](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.html#method_reduceComputed).  Basically, you can do something like this:

```
Ember.computed.sum = function (dependentKey) {
  return Ember.reduceComputed.call(null, dependentKey, {
    initialValue: 0,

    addedItem: function (accumulatedValue, item, changeMeta, instanceMeta) {
      return accumulatedValue + item;
    },

    removedItem: function (accumulatedValue, item, changeMeta, instanceMeta) {
      return accumulatedValue - item;
    }
  });
};
```

Then, in your controller do something like this:

```
App.CartController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
    prices:     Ember.computed.mapBy('content', 'fullPrice'),
    totalPrice: Ember.computed.sum('prices')
});
```

Comment: But Ember.computed.sum('@this.@each.fullPrice') return the list of clotheis in cart. If i render this in view 
    <p>Subtotal {{totalPrice}}</p>
On page i give:
    0<App.CartRecord:ember490:1><App.CartRecord:ember492:2><App.CartRecord:ember493:3>

Comment: I updated it to use a new dependent key. I've never actually tried the `@this.@each.fullPrice` style syntax. Let me know if this works better. Here's a jsFiddle of it [in action](http://jsfiddle.net/NQKvy/321/)